# RDBMS : select max("ORDER") + 1 transaction isolation level

Tags: sql, hibernate, transactions, rdbms

I have a table **Tag** which has the following structure and values:

```
    +----+----------+-------+
    | id | name     | order |
    +----+----------+-------+
    | 42 | 'foo'    | 1     |
    +----+----------+-------+
    | 43 | 'bar'    | 3     |
    +----+----------+-------+
    | 44 | 'baz'    | 2     |
    +----+----------+-------+
```

**id** is the internal PK, **name** is a display name and **order** (unique) is the order in which these tags must be displayed ( 'foo', 'baz', 'bar' ). It is possible to create new tags, delete existing tags, and reorder all the tags.

I think I will run into a problem with the way I insert a new tag. I need to do something like (pseudo-code):

```
     begin transaction A;
     select max("order") + 1 into next_order from Tag;
     insert into Tag("name", "order") values('blah', next_order);
     commit A;
```

Of course, concurrently, another transaction may run:

```
     begin transaction B;
     select max("order") + 1 into next_order from Tag;
     insert into Tag("name", "order") values('bluh', next_order);
     commit B;
```

Let's take the highest transaction isolation level **SERIALIZABLE**, I understand that it protects me against phantom read, even if "A" commits while "B" runs, "B" won't see the new row ( 'blah', 4 ).

Unfortunately, "B" and "A" would have selected the same max("order") + 1, and my table after "A" and "B" commit would look like:

```
    +----+------------------+
    | id | name     | order |
    +----+----------+-------+
    | 42 | 'foo'    | 1     |
    +----+----------+-------+
    | 43 | 'bar'    | 3     |
    +----+----------+-------+
    | 44 | 'baz'    | 2     |
    +----+----------+-------+
    | 45 | 'blah'   | 4     |
    +----+----------+-------+ 
    | 46 | 'bluh'   | 4     |
    +----+----------+-------+
```

I hope I am wrong, am I?

If I am not, what is the common pattern to atomically handle "row order" in a table? Shall I lock the entire table while inserting a new row? Or shall I go with *"order" column has no unique constraint, 'blah' and 'bluh' insertion order is undefined, they are both the 4th*?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Use an auto-increment id for the column.  Don't try to implement this logic yourself.

Comment: Use a sequence, it's the only reliable, fast and scalable solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I didn't figure out that "gaps" in the "order" column are not a problem, indeed using a sequence will always generate "the max possible order at that time". I will go that way, thank you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name same reply as Gordon Linoff's one, you're both right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What if user delete a tag, or want change the order.

I wll lock the table. You probably will need Triggers for Insert/Update/Delete.

So the insert should work normal using `order = null`, and put the transaction logic inside the triggers.